# Subseting with ddply

Tags: r

I know this should be straightforward, but I am having problems splitting a data frame with ddply.

```
ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4,4,4,4)
date = c("4th Nov","4th Nov","5th Nov","5th Nov","6th Nov","7th Nov","7th Nov","8th Nov","6th Nov","6th Nov","7th Nov","7th Nov")
df<-data.frame(ID,date)
```

All I want is to work out the number of unique IDs I have in a very large dataset (so in the example above I would just get 4).  The numbers in my real dataset are not continuous though, so I can't just work out the maximum.

I have been trying to get the code to split the dataframe so each unique ID will just be included once in the new dataframe, and then I was hoping just to count the number of rows to give me the total.  Perhaps I don't even need ddply - could I just do this in one line of code?

Sorry for my ignorance, and thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quickest and easiest way is to use `length` and `unique` on your vector of IDs:

```
> length(unique(df$ID))
[1] 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need ddply here but here is solution with ddply:

```
nrow(ddply(df,.(ID),head,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
records=ddply(
              df, .(date),
              summarise,
              days=length(unique(ID))              
              )
```